# DOM Exception 18 while Detecting pixel color on a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas

I am trying to finish HTML5/javascript game and testing it in crome.
Whever i am pointing over the image for detecting pixel color There an error display in console.

- Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data. e001-4.html:27
- Uncaught Error: SecurityError: DOM Exception 18

Please tell me what is it and what'wrong in the code.

Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Canvas Example 4 (Detecting Colors)</title>
<script>
window.onload = function () {
var preview = document.getElementById('preview');
var r = document.getElementById('r');
var g = document.getElementById('g');
var b = document.getElementById('b');
var a = document.getElementById('a');
var mx = document.getElementById('mx');
var my = document.getElementById('my');
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', move, false);
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
var building = new Image()
building.src = "img/sprite1.png";
draw();
function draw () {
c.drawImage(building, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
function move (e) {
mx.innerHTML = e.clientX;
my.innerHTML = e.clientY;
var img = c.getImageData(e.clientX, e.clientY, 1, 1);
var idata = img.data;
var red = idata[0];
var green = idata[1];
var blue = idata[2];
var alpha = idata[3];
r.innerHTML = red;
g.innerHTML = green;
b.innerHTML = blue;
a.innerHTML = (alpha > 0) ? alpha : 'Transparent';
var rgba='rgba(' + red + ', ' + green + ', ' + blue + ', ' + alpha + ')';
preview.style.backgroundColor =rgba;
}
}
</script>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
canvas {
border: 1px solid black;
float: left;
}
ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
padding: 0px;
float: left;
}
ul li { font-weight: bold; }
ul li span { font-weight: normal; }
ul li #preview { width: 50px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid black; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300">
Your browser doesn't include support for the canvas tag.
</canvas>
<ul>
<li><div id="preview"></div></li>
<li>Red: <span id="r">NULL</span></li>
<li>Green: <span id="g">NULL</span></li>
<li>Blue: <span id="b">NULL</span></li>
<li>Alpha: <span id="a">NULL</span></li>
<li>Mouse X: <span id="mx">NULL</span></li>
<li>Mouse Y: <span id="my">NULL</span></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you running this on a webserver? This usually happens when you draw an image from another domain, but the adress you're using suggests it's from the same domain, so something else must be going in, for instance running on the `file://` protocol would do this

Comment: Yes I am using file:// protocol , But i want to know how to avoid it and run it locally.

Comment: The only way to avoid that is to install a webserver, WAMP, EasyPHP etc. comes to mind, and you really can't develop anything without it IMO.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A local web server is a very useful development tool.

But, if you just want to test images while satisfying CORS requirements then check out dropbox.com.

If you sign up and put your images in your public folder, then you can satisfy CORS restrictions by applying building.crossOrigin="anonymous";

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a local Web server and serve the page from it.
Example use apache and put the file in htdoc folder and look for the result.